# Insert seam into a numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy matrix with values in it. They won't be all the same, but the example is easier if I show it like this:

```
input = np.array([
  [1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1]
])
```

Now I have another matrix of the same size. There is a "seam" of numbers, one number per column (not more, not less). The position they are in the `seam` matrix is where I want to insert them into the `input` matrix. All values in the input matrix are moved to the right.

For example if you apply this "seam"

```
seam = np.array([
  [0, 2, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 3, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 4]
])
```

to the `input` matrix, I want this output:

```
output = np.array([
  [1, 2, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 3, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 4, 1]
])
```

The input and seam matrix will always have the exact same dimensions. The output will have the same height and width + 1 of the input.

Is there an efficient way to perform this insertion?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the straight-forward way using a mask to rearrange the input values:

```
>>> m, n = seam.shape
>>> output = np.empty((m, n+1), input.dtype)
>>> mask = np.ones((m, n+1), dtype=bool)
>>> nz = np.where(seam)
>>> mask[nz] = False
>>> output[mask]=input.ravel()
>>> output[nz]=seam[nz]
>>> output
array([[1, 2, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 3, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 4, 1]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a zero initialized array and assign your items according their indices:

```
In [24]: nonzero_ind = np.nonzero(seam)

In [25]: x, y = input.shape

In [26]: arr = np.zeros((x, y+1))

In [27]: arr[nonzero_ind] = seam[nonzero_ind]

In [28]: arr[np.where(arr==0)] = input.ravel()

In [29]: arr
Out[29]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  3.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  4.,  1.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

here is my work arround :

getting the indexes of non null values in steam :

```
indices = np.nonzero(seam.ravel())
```

Getting the corresponding values

```
values = seam[np.nonzero(seam)]
```

and inserting the values at the given position :

```
np.insert(input_array.ravel(),indices[0], values ).reshape(input_array.shape[0], input_array.shape[1]+1)
```